# AssertJ to Hamcrest equivalency (only for Spring MVC Test): How test each POJO item of a collection (with dates)

Tags: junit, hamcrest, spring-mvc-test, assertj

For a `Spring Framework` App, about Testing:

- The business layer is working  with `AssertJ` and `JUnit`.
- The web layer is working with `JUnit` and `Spring MVC Test`, where the latter works **mandatorily** with `Hamcrest`. See [Is there a way to use AssertJ assertions with Spring MVC Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447446/is-there-a-way-to-use-assertj-assertions-with-spring-mvc-test) (The answer is **no** yet)

If in `AssertJ` is possible apply the following for a *collection*:

```
.containsExactly(tuple("087", "Peter", "Jordani", parse("1980-01-01")),
                 ...
                 tuple("088", "Isaias", "Jordano", parse("1980-01-01")))
```

What could be the best equivalent approximation of these three methods:

- `containsExactly`
- `tuple`
- `parse`

To be applied in:

```
 .andExpect(model().attribute("personas", ???)
```

I did a research in google:

- about collections there are samples for simple collections (`String`, `Integer` with `hasItems`)
- about dates, is working *only* with `Date` objects, of course same type, but not with `String` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look on these tests examples:

```
public class Test {
        private List<Person> personList;
        private Person peter = new Person("087", "Peter", parse("1980-01-01"));
        private Person john = new Person("081", "John", parse("1980-01-22"));

        @BeforeEach
        void setup() {
            personList = new ArrayList<>();
            personList.add(peter);
            personList.add(john);
        }

        @Test
        void assertjTest() {
            assertThat(personList).extracting("age", "name", "date")
                    .containsExactly(
                            tuple("087", "Peter", parse("1980-01-01")),
                            tuple("081", "John", parse("1980-01-22"))
                    );
        }

        @Test
        void hamcrestTest() {
            org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(personList,
                    contains(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("age", is("087")),
                                    hasProperty("name", is("Peter")),
                                    hasProperty("date", is(parse("1980-01-01")))
                            ),
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("age", is("081")),
                                    hasProperty("name", is("John")),
                                    hasProperty("date", is(parse("1980-01-22")))
                            )
                    ));

        }
}
```

And let's review in details:

**containsExactly**

`contains` method is an alternative for it. Whereas `hasItem` is more like `assertj.contains`.

**tuple**

May be replaced by combination of `allOf` and `hasProperty`. In my opinion it looks ugly and I would think about just using `new Person("a","b","c")`. Unless you have some extra fields that you do not want to verify.

**parse**

Here I've just used same method for both of them. If you will take a more precise look on it, you will notice that this method has nothing to do with matchers. It is just parses string to date using `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`. If you don't want to use `assertj's` you could easily extract it to some util class.

Comment: Thank u. It works. About (1) `Whereas hasItem is more like assertj.contains` could you add a **new** `@Test` method about that?, I am not sure to understand your point. (2) `In my opinion it looks ugly and I would think about just using new Person("a","b","c")` Even if is ugly (I am agree, is verbose) is for presentation purposes to understand what have been returned, **but** could you add a **new** `@Test` method about that?. (3) I understand, just curious, where appears `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`? I did do `Ctrl + Click` starting in the `parse` method, I couldn't find that sentence

Comment: @ManuelJordan 1) to understand it better you may want to try it by yourself. Create a list with TWO persons and try to run contains and hasItem with ONE person. Results will be different. 2) Instead of comparing exact fields, you could compare entire objects, like contains(new Person(1,2,3,), new Person(2,4,5)).3) You should take a more precise look, everything is there:D